# uploading file issue, error not displaying

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am trying to restrict the file size when a user uploads. I have the following function:

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';        
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '50';
        //$config['max_width'] = '1024';
        //$config['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $fullImagePath;
        if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && !empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
        {
              if (! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
              {
                   $error = array('file_error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                   //print_r($error);

                   $this->load->view('layout/header');
                   $this->load->view('register', $error);
                   $this->load->view('layout/footer');

              }else{
                  // set a $_POST value for 'image' that we can use later
                  $upload_data    = $this->upload->data();
                  $fullImagePath = '/uploads/' . $upload_data['file_name']; 
              }
        }       
        //path of image on the server
        return $fullImagePath;
    }
```

If I print the $error array above, it shows the error that the file is too large, which is what I want. But the problem is if I don't print it, the whole process is completed even if the picture is too big, and the data in the database is complete. How can I fix this?

Comment: The code you posted has no interaction with the database so it's hard to tell why you are getting data saved there. Also, when you say "the whole process completed" do you mean the file is uploaded to the server as well? Or just that there is data in the db?

Answer (score 0):

Your return is outside of the else. You want:

`return $fullImagePath;`

to be underneath

`$fullImagePath = '/uploads/' . $upload_data['file_name'];`

otherwise it will return regardless of whether it's errored or not, which I'm guessing is then sent to your database..?